# How to remove tabbar from the top when I am navigating to another page from one of the tab in react native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator, react-native-tab-view

Everyone I am facing an issue in react-native as I am new to this .

I am callling a tabbpage from homePage
so in tabpage there is a navbar at the top,below this navbar a tabbar is showing two tabs.[image]

This is good till now but the problem starts from here 
In tabPage I have two tabs ->tab1 and tab2 
from tab1 I am navigating to page MainPage1 where it is showing a Navbar below navbar a tabbar below tabbar an another navbar. As shown in the picture.[image]

I am totally unable to remove both the top level navbar having title **"Stopages"** and the tabbar.

I am using Tabview for creating this tabbpage and using stacknavigator for navigating to different pages.I am stuck here and Not able to find solution

NOTE->I have tried using

```
      navigationOptions: {
      tabBar: ({ state }) => ({
       visible: false
       })
```

but its not doing anything Please help

```
   class TabPage extends React.Component{
   state = {
   index: 0,
    routes: [
     { key: 'Stopagess', title: 'Stopages' },
     { key: 'MapStopagess', title: 'Maps' },
    ],
   };

   render() {
   return (
           <TabView

         navigationState={this.state}
         renderScene={SceneMap({
         Stopagess: Stopages,
         MapStopagess: MapStopages,
             })
            }
             renderTabBar={props =>
              <TabBar
                {...props}
                style = {{backgroundColor:'#3f51b5'}}
                indicatorStyle={{ color: 'pink' }}
              />
            }
      onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
      initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}
      indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}

       />
      );
      }

      }
```

This is my Stopages class

```
     class Stopages extends Component { 
     render()
    {
       return (
      <StopageDetail/>
     )
      } 
      }

       const StopageDetail = createStackNavigator({
      Stp:{
      screen: Stpforsomeissue,
     navigationOptions: () => ({
     header:null,
     tabBarVisible: false,
      }),



       },
       NextDetailStopage:{
      screen :StopageDetailOfStudents,
     navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({

     title:  'Stopages Detail',
    // tabBarVisible: navigation.state.params=false,
       headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#ffd600'},
   />,
   })
  }
  })
```

Comment: can you post the code of your stacknavigator please

Comment: I have posted the updated code please help

Comment: instead of 'header:null', change it to headerMode: 'none'

Comment: Not working ....if uisng in NextDetailStopage then removing the last navbar and if using in Stp then showing no changes.I just want that in StopageDetailPage there should be only one navbar and remove all the topbars as shown in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using createMaterialTopNavigator under a root stack with routeName `Stopages` and under each Tab route you have a dedicated stack for each one, the first one being the `Stopages Detail`. Please correct me if thats not the case and edit your post to show the navigation stack you have written.

This might be useful to you:

The root stack can be like the one below:

```
createStackNavigator ({
   StopPages: {screen: MyTabNavigator, navigationOptions: {header: null}}
});
```

and the TabNavigator will be like this:

```
const MyTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Stopages:  {screen: StopagesStack},
  Maps:  {screen: MapsStack},
});

const StopagesStack = createStackNavigator({
  StopagesDetail: {screen: DetailContainer, navigationOptions: {header: null}}
});
```

The key to hide default stack navigator's header is to set it null in the navigationOptions.

Comment: No I am not using  createMaterialTopNavigator  instead I am using TabView.I am posting my tab code.Please check my edited code

Comment: navigationOptions: {header: null} its not working .Still stucked

Answer (score 0):

You can play around within `navigationOptions` within a tab of `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` in order which ones had TopTabBar or not, Example:

```js
export const Dashboard = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: FirstScreen, // This is my first Tab (a View)
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'First'
    }
  },
  Second: {
    screen: SecondStack, // This is another Stack
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'SecondStack',
      tabBarVisible: navigation.state.index === 0, //Tab bar will be visible depending of the state (you can put another index)
      animationEnabled: true
    })
  },
  Third: {
    screen: ThirdScreen, // This is my third Tab (a View)
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'ThirdScreen',
    }
  }
});
```